# CakePHP: adding DISTINCT to find causes an associated to get omitted

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0

We build a fairly complex set of $conditions, then we search using Paginator:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array( 'conditions'=>$conditions, 
                      'joins'=>$joins, 
                      'limit'=>25,
                      //'fields' => array('DISTINCT (User.id)') 
                );
$resume_display_array = $this->Paginator->paginate('User');
```

You'll see the `'fields'` is commented out. When we uncomment that field, it causes associated model `Resume` to get dropped from the results array (without it, each result returned includes a [Resume] key.

Why is this happening?

Here's the SQL dump WITH the DISTINCT option in use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`User`.`id`), `User`.`id` 
FROM `sw`.`users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings_users` AS `TaggingUser` 
  ON (`User`.`id`= `TaggingUser`.`user_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings` AS `Tagging` 
  ON (`TaggingUser`.`tagging_id`= `Tagging`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`resumes` AS `Resume` 
  ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `User`.`first_name` LIKE '%jordan%' AND NOT (`Tagging`.`tag_name` = ('done')) 
LIMIT 25
```

Here's the SQL dump WITHOUT the DISTINCT option:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`wordpress_user_id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`group_id`, `Resume`.`id`, `Resume`.`user_id`, `Resume`.`wordpress_resume_id`, `Resume`.`wordpress_user_id`, `Resume`.`has_file`, `Resume`.`is_stamped`, `Resume`.`is_active`, `Resume`.`file_extension`, `Resume`.`created`, `Resume`.`modified`, `Resume`.`is_deleted` 
FROM `sw`.`users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings_users` AS `TaggingUser` 
  ON (`User`.`id`= `TaggingUser`.`user_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings` AS `Tagging` 
  ON (`TaggingUser`.`tagging_id`= `Tagging`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `sw`.`resumes` AS `Resume` 
  ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `User`.`first_name` LIKE '%jordan%' AND NOT (`Tagging`.`tag_name` = ('done')) 
LIMIT 25
```

**Update**

Here is a var_dump of `$joins`:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'table' => 'taggings_users',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'alias' => 'TaggingUser',
        'conditions' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'User.id= TaggingUser.user_id'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'table' => 'taggings',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'alias' => 'Tagging',
        'conditions' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'TaggingUser.tagging_id= Tagging.id'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Would you mind to var_dump $joins variable? it's weird that Resumes is still there, but using a different database streetofwalls, instead of sw

Comment: @VancleiP Sorry that was a copy/paste mistake. I fixed the incorrect database name. Also, I added the var_dump() of the $joins array.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the `fields` option, you need to specify all fields that you want to retrieve.

By setting it ONLY to `User.id`, you're telling it that that is the ONLY field you want returned.

You could also try something like below as a catchall (not sure if that works, but if not, you get the idea - you're limiting your own results):

```
'fields' => array('*', 'DISTINCT (User.id)')
```

Comment: This sounds promising, but I get an SQL error when I use `'fields' => array('*', 'DISTINCT (User.id)')`. I'll add below...

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT (User.id), id, `User`.`id` FROM `sw`.`users` AS `User` LEFT ' at line 1

Comment: SQL Query: SELECT *, DISTINCT (User.id), id, `User`.`id` FROM `sw`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings_users` AS `TaggingUser` ON (`User`.`id`= `TaggingUser`.`user_id`) LEFT JOIN `sw`.`taggings` AS `Tagging` ON (`TaggingUser`.`tagging_id`= `Tagging`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `sw`.`resumes` AS `Resume` ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`first_name` LIKE '%jordan%' AND NOT (`Tagging`.`tag_name` = ('done')) LIMIT 25

Comment: Also, it's interesting to note that even when I use my origin `DISTINCT` clause, it does not cause all associated models to get stripped out. *Just* the Resume array. I still see Attempts, etc.

Comment: Try this one:  'fields' => array('DISTINCT (User.id)', 'User.username', 'Table.field' .... ) instead of *.